# Advantages of Sybase's AseClient for ADO.Net 2 over the ODBC driver

Tags: performance, ado.net, sap-ase

We have an ETL process that reads data from a Sybase DB via the ODBC "Adaptive Server Enterprise" driver v12.05

I'm wondering if there any any performance advantages specifically to migrating to the .Net 2 Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.dll ?

Answer (score 3):

I think that it's obvious that the native provider will be faster than the outdated ODBC.
Check [this](http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/performance-benchmarks-odbc-vs-oracle-mysql-sql-server-net-providers) for a similar comparison.